# Why can't I access a public var using the getter?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

having a file containing these statements:

```
public:
boost::shared_ptr<TBFControl::TbfCmdHandler> _tbfCmdHandlerPtr;
// will be private later...

boost::shared_ptr<TBFControl::TbfCmdHandler> getTBFCmdHandler()
{ return _tbfCmdHandlerPtr; }
```

I can use it this way:

```
boost::shared_ptr<TBFControl::TbfCmdHandler>myTbfCmdHandlerPtr(
    this->getTBFInstallation()-> _tbfCmdHandlerPtr );
```

but not, like i want, this way:

```
boost::shared_ptr<TBFControl::TbfCmdHandler>myTbfCmdHandlerPtr(
    this->getTBFInstallation()->getTBFCmdHandler() );
```

Using the getter function, the following error occurs:

> 'Housekeeping::TBFInstallation::getTBFCmdHandler'
>   : cannot convert 'this' pointer from
>   'const Housekeeping::TBFInstallation'
>   to 'Housekeeping::TBFInstallation &'

what is going wrong here?

Comment: How is `getTBFInstallation()` declared?

Comment: BTW: It's not necessary to put `this->` at the start of those statements, unless you also have a local variable (or locally declared function!) called `getTBFInstallation`.

Comment: j_random_hacker, it could be necessary, depending on whether the function was inherited and where it was inherited form. I actually prefer to always prefix calls with `this->` for the sake of readability (I don't do it for variables though, I prefix those with `m_`).

Comment: I prefer to use the this when refering to methods. Just make it easier during code reviews to know that the symbol is a local method, since it could also be a type, a free-function or a variable.

Comment: @avakar: By all means use `this->` for clarity's sake, but it makes no difference, regardless of whether the function is inherited, and where it's inherited from: in both cases name lookup looks for methods in the current class first (including non-hidden inherited methods), before checking namespace and finally global names. The *only* semantic difference `this->` can make is if you have a local variable/function declaration with that name in an enclosing block. (See 3.4.1/8 in the standard.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker, that is incorrect. Without `this->` prefix, dependent bases are not searched.

Comment: @avakar: I'm sorry, you're absolutely right. After much hunting, I found 14.6.2/3 which says exactly this. It can only affect class templates whose base classes are parameterised (e.g. for CRTP). I can't help but think this rule is an ugly wart mind you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously, `this->getTBFInstallation()` returns a const pointer. You need to make the function `getTBFCmdHandler` const as well.

```
boost::shared_ptr<TBFControl::TbfCmdHandler> getTBFCmdHandler() const
{
    return _tbfCmdHandlerPtr;
}
```

Note the `const` keyword at the end of the first line.

**Edit:** By adding `const`,  you're in effect changing the type of `this` from `TBFInstallation *` to `TBFInstallation const *`. Basically, by adding the `const`, you're saying that the function can be called even when the object on which the function is being called is const.

Comment: Goz, yes, that would work too. Since `getTBFCmdHandler` is a getter function, however, it's probably better to do it my way.

Comment: it works, but i did not understand why I have to write the const at the end of the function, i would had assumed to write const before the function, but that did not work.

Comment: The const at the end basically says you have a constant this pointer.  If you are calling on a const class pointer than the function needs a const this or it won't work ...

Answer (score 1):

`getTBFInstallation()` is (apparently) returning a const pointer. However, `getTBFCmdHandler()` is a non-const member function and can therefore not be called on a const pointer. Solution: Make `getTBFCmdHandler()` a const member function

Answer (score 1):

Without having seen the code I would guess that `getTBFInstallation()` returns a `const TBFInstallation` on which you're trying to call a non const function.